# ruby 1.8.7 unicode regular expression question

Tags: ruby, regex

How can I make this regular expression work in ruby 1.8.7?

```
regexp = /[^ёЁа-яА-Яa-zA-Zà-üÀ-Ü0-9\.\-\+_]/
```

It should work the following

```
"⟲«Du côté des chars lourds»_123.doc".gsub(regexp, "_"): "__Du_côté_des_chars_lourds__123.doc"
```

In ruby 1.9.2 it works, but not in ruby 1.8.7.

Comment: Because it's in a gem that should be available to users of ruby 1.8.7 too. :)

Comment: Seems to be working on Rubular, which is also using 1.8.7: http://www.rubular.com/r/SnEByiEjQv

Comment: Could it be the ruby source file encoding issue?

Comment: That's really strange. I just tried it again using ree-1.8.7-2011.03 and irb and it does not work. Could somebody else try using ree and irb?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Append the `u` (Unicode) modifier to your regular expression:

```
regexp = /[^ёЁа-яА-Яa-zA-Zà-üÀ-Ü0-9\.\-\+_]/u
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! Do you know how I can pass this option using Regexp.new? Regexp.new('...', 'u') does not seem to work.

Comment: @gucki, character encoding modifiers go into the third argument. Try: `Regexp.new("...", nil, "u")`.